# Best way to display web content for specific country using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Need a big help from you.
I need an advice from all you good people out there.

I have some contents that i need to display only to few countries.I am okay with getting the user's country with Geoip.i am storing my content in MySQL database with a country_code field.country code can be empty or any single code or group of comma separated values

What i want to do is,

1. checking country_code and if it is empty, display that content for all users.
2. if country_code is not empty and only a single value,display content only for the given country_code users.
3. if country_code is group of comma separated values,display contents for all the comma separated country users.

i have two options for do this

1. adding data columns for `each` country separately and display contents
   as for example `three columns` for three countries US,UK,AU and if user's location is US,

   `$sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content_table WHERE US=='$country_code'"))`;
2. adding country data for single column as country_code and store US,UK,AU and if user's location is US,

   `$sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content_table WHERE country_code!=''"));
   $pieces = explode(",", $sql['country_code']);
   foreach($pieces as $val){
   if($country_code=="US")
   //display content
   }`

NOTE:**amount of countries may differs according to my needs**

what will be the best practice to overcome this,

- using different columns to different country make fast search but adding more columns is not good i think
- using single column and iterate comma separated values needs more computation

What should i do..??
please advice me on this.. OR do you have any idea better than this..? Thanks

Comment: A previous answer I wrote [may be of a little help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796046/wordpress-use-method-post-for-multiple-language-selection/11796069#11796069) to you.

Comment: You could make a second table with country_code as an index in both tables, the second table containing just the content_id + country_code; then WHERE EXISTS (SELECT cc.* FROM `content_countries` cc WHERE cc.country_code='".mysql_real_escape_string($country_code)."' OR cc.country_code='ALL')

Comment: Thanks Fluffeh for your response.i have read your post.sorry icouldnt find a solution for my problem. Thanks anyway dear friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * 
    FROM content_table 
    WHERE country_code = '' 
    OR country_code REGEXP ',?". $user_country_code .",?'"));
```

If I understood you well, you want to show elements to the user only if the user country code is in the `country_code` field or if the `country_code` is not specified ?

This should do it, even if a database solution would be better.

Comment: yes Bartimeus,but what happen if the country_code has more than one country code separate with commas?

Comment: Well with this code it works, except if you're talking about the *user* country code.

Comment: Oh Sorry friend just got the idea of your code Thanks i will try and let you know thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'd just say - create a countries table

```
countries
id, code, name
1, UK , United Kingdom
```

..... and rest of the countries

In your `content` table just add another column country_id or country_code

```
Content
id, title, body, country_code
1, some text, more text, 1
```

then in your sql

just `select * from content where country_code = 'UK' or country_id = 1` // depending on which option you go for

OR

create a separate linking table for allowing content for multiple countries

```
content_country
content_id, country_id
1, 2
1, 1
1, 3
```

To fetch content your queries use `left/right/inner` join e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM `content` c
LEFT JOIN content_country cc ON cc.content_id = c.id
AND cc.country_id
IN ( 2, 4 )
```

Comment: Thanks HappyApe for your immediate response. What if i want to display the selected content for two or more countries? as your code it'll easy if it contents only one country i guess.

Comment: see above the OR part - create a linking table content_country, (so you'd have 3 tables , content, countries, content_country)

Comment: Thanks HappyApe. I think your answer is the best solution. only problem is i need to add another table for multiple countries.I have more than one content tables to display as above. that means i need several tables more. Thanks for your Help buddy. I will accept your answer after checking around the others viewpoints okay..??

Comment: I have accept another answer as for solution because it makes sense to me.I am appreciating your valuable answer and upvoted it. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: No problem. Every solution has their own ups/downs so if another solution solves your problem better then yes go for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try It:

$sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM content_table WHERE country_code!=''")); 

$pieces = explode(",", $sql['country_code']); 


# No Need to run loop 
#foreach($pieces as $val)
#{ 
#    if($country_code=="US") //display content 
#}

if(!empty($pieces))    // 
{

    if(in_array($user_country_code,$pieces ))
    {
        echo "display content";
    }
}
else
{
        echo "display content";    // for all country
}

Use in_array() except of loop. I guess you will use in on user login so you will have user_country_code.
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul,does in_array() is faster than foreach()?

Comment: Yes so i am saying. use most of php functions and try to write minimum code.