# Want to hide content for specific countries

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, apache, ip

I want to hide content and redirect some specific countries (Like Iran, Pakistan, Afghanistan) traffic to other web pages which is specially built for it but I  want to show this content to other countries traffic how it's possible Please help me

Comment: Could you provide some code mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the IP using `$_SERVER` then use `http://api.hostip.info/country.php?ip=100.100.100.100` to trace country and then apply redirects to it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to determine from the user what country they are in, and then save that information to a Session or Cookie so that your code can reference it. While it is possible to guess at IP ranges and perhaps guess at location based off local user time settings (starting to get really tricky at this point) the simplest way is to simply ask the user.

If you are after code samples, I wrote a fairly lengthy answer to this very similar question that you might be interested in as well: [Wordpress: Use method="post" for multiple language selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796046/wordpress-use-method-post-for-multiple-language-selection/11796069#11796069)

Answer (score 0):

You need a service like [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/). Your server-side code must check the IP address against an API or IP-to-location database and block from there. Blocking content through JavaScript **may** block some clients but it is easy to bypass it.