# Using multiple languages

Tags: php, html

Say, I have a html with some text.

```
<html>
<body>


<div><h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1></div>
<div><p>Some text.</p></div>
<div><p>Some more text.</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Say, I want to use multiple languages, like English and German. How should I do it? Should I make 2 files `EN.php` and `DE.php` with string in those languages, and should my `html` look like this? I mean should it have `<?php...?>` for each string?

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'EN.php';?>

<div><h1><?php echo "$a";?></h1></div>
<div><p><?php echo "$b"; ?></p></div>
<div><p><?php echo "$c";?></p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would suggest reading this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796046/wordpress-use-method-post-for-multiple-language-selection/11796069#11796069) and the answer I provided along with the others. Best way is to simply keep all your data in a table, along with the language and page you are looking for - then depending on user selection, display the page in the language they want to see it in.

Comment: My problem is not really the language selection, it's the implementation. Question is if I should write <?php...?> for each string.

Comment: The answer is: It depends. You should do some research about translating websites and how PHP can help you with that along the lines (and how it can be used to shoot into your feet). Then choose something that has the best trade-offs for your specific use-case. Alternatively we can toss a coin and then answer Yes or No.

Comment: Read the answer, it covers how to implement it.

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: Well instead of having to write <?...?> for each string, I have to write an if...else, so it's kind of the same thing.

Comment: If any of the answers has helped you let us know

Comment: Writing if/else for every translation is crazy. How about creating a language array whose variables are defined in your language packs? `<h1><?php echo $lang['welcome']; ?></h1>`

Comment: FYI putting quotes around single variables is pointless. `echo "$a";` is the same as `echo $a;`

Answer (score 2):

As you are looking on how to translate content that is bound to a specific HTML structure which most likely represents a page and/or an object, so it has all the context necessary for the translation you can make use of the HTML document object model (DOM).

In it's basic form, the HTML is already translated but also marks the texts to translate:

```
<html>
<body>


<div><h1 lang="en:translate">Welcome to my home page!</h1></div>
<div><p lang="en:translate">Some text.</p></div>
<div><p lang="en:translate">Some more text.</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

You then load that HTML into the object model and *compile* the english version of it by stripping all lang tags that contain the "`en:translate`" value for the "`lang`" attribute:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>


<div><h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1></div>
<div><p>Some text.</p></div>
<div><p>Some more text.</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

While doing so, you could also run callbacks that are able to translate each english string into a translated string by using a translation table (which can be as simple as an array in PHP) or a more specific translation mechanism like gettext (which can deal with language specific constructs like plural forms and offers an optimized file-format to store translations). A German page then could easily look like:

```
<html lang="de">
<body>


<div><h1>Willkommen auf meiner Home-Page!</h1></div>
<div><p>A bisserl text.</p></div>
<div><p>Hallelujah! Da ist ja noch mehr Text.</p></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Both the [Document Object Model (DOM)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) as well as [Gettext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) are common mechanism in the fields. Both are well documented, have supporting tools and are available as PHP extensions.

However if this kind of translation matches your exact needs might be questionable. From what you have put in your question as example, it seems like a good fit however, as I already commented, you should do much more research on your own first to get more ideas what is possible and how.

Answer (score 2):

So what you need is something like this:

```
//Language
if(!empty($_GET['language']) && in_array($_GET['language'], $languages)) {
    $_SESSION['language'] = $_GET['language'];
    $language = $_SESSION['language'];
} else if(!empty($_SESSION['language']) && in_array($_SESSION['language'], $languages)) {
    $language = $_SESSION['language'];
} else {
    $_SESSION['language'] = 'Dutch';
}
include_once 'languages/'.$_SESSION['language'].'.php';
```

for each language you have a separate file that has an array called `$language` so you do something like this:

```
$language = array('English' => 'Dutch');
//For other langaue you do almost the same but then:
$langauge = array('English' => 'German');
```

The check if the `$_SESSION['language']` is in an array is just so you don't end up with blank pages

The use in a html file goes like this:

```
<h1><?php echo $language['English']; ?></h1>
```

When the session changes that will pick another translation

I hope this helps if not please let me know

Comment: Why is this different than my solution and isn't better to replace this: $language = array('English' => 'Dutch'); with this $language = array('language' => 'Dutch');

Comment: @Alen I don't say my method is better and `$language = array('English' => 'Dutch');` was just an example

Answer (score 0):

Internationalization and localization are a pretty big subject, but generally the process is that you have a file for each language that specifies a 'key' and then the translated text for that key. Then, in your code, you use a translation function everywhere you want to render some text that takes the target language and the localization key then spits out the translation from the relevant language file.

I've used gettext with great success before, although not in php.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm using multiple languages in most of mine projects and this is my approach:

create file for every language you want in this format:

```
<?php
    $lang = array(
        "rememberMe" => "Erinnern",
        "login" => "ANMELDEN",
        "register" => "REGISTRIEREN",
        "username" => "Benutzername", ...
```

Then echo the language in json format

```
echo json_encode($lang);
```

Now in your application you load your languages using sessions, something like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}

if(isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
        $languages = array("bs", "en", "de");
        if(in_array($_SESSION['lang'], $languages)){
            $langName = $_SESSION['lang'];
            include "lang/$langName.php";
        }else{
            include "lang/en.php";
        }
    }else{
        include "lang/en.php";
    }
```

And when you want to display, for example username you display it like this:

```
echo $lang['username'];
```

Comment: I like this, although I'm not sure where you use the cookies, since you use session.

Comment: Yeah. Still, how should my html look like, using this? I mean how does it recognize echo $lang['username']; ? I still have to do <p><?php echo $lang['username'];?></p>

Comment: It depends which language file you include, if you include de.php it will give german words, if you include en.php it will give you english words etc. You should implement page where user selects language and then you save language information in cookie